# Read epub file path

Tags: objective-c, epub, nsbundle

There are two files in my project,one is pdf and other is epub.

```
            NSString *str1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"delhi" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jackson" ofType:@"epub"];
```

my problem is str1 is giving path correctly,but str is giving nil.So is it any way to find the path of type "epub".

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure both of the files are included in Xcode's copy phase.
2. Make sure the case of the file and extensions is ok, it can work on simulator but won't on real device.

Answer (score 1):

The `nil` result means that there is no *jackson.epub* at the top level of your app bundle. Either you forgot to include it in the Copy Files build phase or you've gotten the name wrong (capitalization counts).

Answer (score 0):

Some times we will drag files in our projects to add but they are not loaded in "NSBundle" so we will get nil path. To conform click on main project file icon  and then switch to tab "Build Phases" Click to "Add" sign to add your required file if not available here.[image]